# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push') react.js

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, next.js, jsx, chakra-ui

I want to link an internal page to an `<IconButton>`, but when I try to do it either with `<Link>` or with `onClick={() => router.push(Page)}` it returns the same error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'push')`. How can I solve this problem? Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { VStack,IconButton } from '@chakra-ui/react';
import {BsFillPersonFill, BsWrench, BsBriefcaseFill, BsEnvelopeFill} from 'react-icons/bs'                     
import About from './About';


function Navbar() {
    const router = useRouter()
    return (
        <VStack>

             <IconButton onClick={() => router.push(About)} icon={<BsFillPersonFill />} rounded="full" right="830" top="-300"></IconButton>
             <IconButton icon={<BsWrench />} rounded="full" right="830" top="-300" ></IconButton>
             <IconButton icon={<BsBriefcaseFill />} rounded="full" right="830" top="-300" ></IconButton>
             <IconButton icon={<BsEnvelopeFill />} rounded="full" right="830" top="-300" ></IconButton>

        </VStack>
    )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 3):

It should take an URL on the onClick listener, It seems you provide it a component

like this:

```
router.push('/about')
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerpush

Comment: I already tried like that, it still gives me that error :(

Comment: @SaverioScagnoli Does project has `/about` url?

Comment: yeah it has, I tried to move it in every folder possible, but it still gave me the error

Comment: @SaverioScagnoli The `about` page should be under `/pages/about.js` for `router.push('/about')` to work as intended.